# Problem starting apache

Tags: apache2, 9.10

Before the question let me give some background info:

I have Ubuntu karmic installed on top of android on my asus transformer. I have also installed netbeans, git, tightvncserver and openssh.

I am viewing the desktop using an android vnc viewer app. Tightvnc is listening on port 5900 and 5901.

Now for the question/problem I have. I have installed apache2. It installed without a problem. When I start the apache service it show in terminal that it is initializing without a problem, but when I check the ports using netstat -tulpn I don't see apache listening on any ports. All I see is tightvnc.

This is the error I see in the apache error.log file.

```
[warn] pid file /var/run/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[emerg] (38)Function not implemented: Couldn't create accept lock (/var/lock/apache2/accept.lock.13752) (5)
```

This is show various times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add any modules to apache ? Any other errors in your logs (I know they can be cryptic).

Comment: I did add mysql and php5 modules. But removed them when I noticed the error to see if they were the cause. There are not other errors in the log.

Comment: Take a look at `sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl configtest` see if that gives a clue.

Comment: The response is "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for Servername" and Syntax OK

Comment: That is a common message https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Troubleshooting_Apache

Comment: Yeah I've seen it before. But would it be the cause of the problem I'm having. Apache just won't start...or doesn't seem to be listening to any ports at all

Comment: Did the fix for the servername, but it didn't seem to solve my problem

Comment: Is there anything unusual about how you installed or disabled php or mysql ? did you use apt-get ? Unless anyone else has a suggestion you can try purging apache, mysql, and php, ( ` sudo apt-get purge ...) and re-install just apache. If you still get an error message, perhaps a bug report.

Comment: I'll try that, if I remember I used apt-get remove ...

Comment: the difference between the two, remove leaves the configuration file ( in /etc ) in place, purge removes the configuration files as well as the package. You may need to re-install and then purge.

Comment: Did you build your own kernel? Googleage shows this error is related to lack of System V IPC in the kernel.

Comment: I actually used a kernel found on androlinux.com. I believe it is a custom build, so that might explain things. Is there a way to check to System V IPC?

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered. I'm going to rebuild the kernel and post what I find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to lack of System V IPC in the kernel.

If you have the config file used to build the kernel, you can check for it; for example, in stock Ubuntu at the moment (the config filename will change depending on your exact version)

```
grep CONFIG_SYSVIPC /boot/config-3.0.0-13-generic
```

Gives:

```
CONFIG_SYSVIPC=y
```

(amongst other things, but that's the important one).

In some kernels, you can also check `/proc/config.gz` if `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` is turned on; that gives you a gzipped dump of the currently running kernel's option (so use `zgrep` on it). Ubuntu's stock kernels don't have this turned on but you're unlikely to need it with those because the packages give you the config file anyway.

The solution: use the stock Ubuntu kernel (it's really quite good and has pretty much everything compiled in that you're ever likely to need) - or rebuild your custom kernel with this turned on.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. My entire boot folder is empty. I'll rebuild the kernel. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

FYI I fixed this by adding the line

```
AcceptMutex fcntl
```

to the bottom of apache2.conf

Answer (score -1):

I met the same error on Android with a chroot ubuntu distribution.
I just change the following apache option (apache2.conf):

**AcceptMutex flock**

And it works for me. I hope it help.

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. Thank you for the answer!